# Text only copied using execCommand on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to copy text from a textarea without having to click on a button. I'm using `execCommand('copy')` and I can get it to copy the text but only when the button has been clicked and not programmatically.

Is there a way to do this?

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var area = document.querySelector('textarea');

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  area.select();
  var msg = document.execCommand('copy') ? "successful" : "unsuccessful";
  console.log("Copy " + msg);
});

button.click(); // Does not copy successfully
```

```html
<textarea>Text to Copy</textarea>
<button>Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, changes to the clipboard must be initiated by the user.

See: https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html#dfn-the-copy-command

> Copy commands triggered from document.execCommand() will only affect
>   the contents of the real clipboard if the event is dispatched from an
>   event that is trusted and triggered by the user, or if the
>   implementation is configured to allow this. How implementations can be
>   configured to allow write access to the clipboard is outside the scope
>   of this specification.